# NPM Start Does Not Display Page With Webpack Build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am new to webpack and am currently going through a tutorial. When I run `npm start`, I do not see any webpage at `locahost:8080`.

The command line output is

```
npm start

> webpack-react-tut@1.0.0 start /Users/user/www/sites/Playground/webpack-react-tut
> webpack-dev-server --open --mode development

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: bb4f4d6aa6d68fd2e7d4
Version: webpack 4.28.4
Time: 2117ms
Built at: 01/19/2019 6:16:27 PM
       Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
./index.html  703 bytes          [emitted]  
     main.js    1.2 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src 40 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/ansi-html/index.js] 4.16 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/events/events.js] 13.3 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/html-entities/index.js] 231 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/node-libs-browser/node_modules/punycode/punycode.js] 14.3 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/url/url.js] 22.8 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8080] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 7.78 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.58 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] (webpack)-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/index.js] 72 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/js/components/container/FormContainer.jsx] 3.66 KiB {main} [built]
    + 26 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html] 705 bytes {0} [built]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-react-tut",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
      "build": "webpack --mode production",
      "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.28.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
}
```

Could someone tell me what I am missing?

Edit:

webpack.config.json

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: What does your webpack file look like

Comment: @Turan see the edit.

Comment: "I do not see any webpage at `locahost:8080`" that means that the page cannot open, like connection refused? Or there is just a blank page? Is it possible that there is some console error in the browser?

Comment: @alex-rokabilis No, not a blank page. The page that one gets when connection to a server could not be made.